# Convert C++ COM class to C# for invocation by C++ executable

Tags: c#, c++, interface, com

Apologies but this is a C++ integration with C# question from a C# person!

I have a C++ EXE which invokes methods from an COM DLL which is registered as an InProcServer32 with a specific class ID.

The EXE is invoked thus:

```
EXENAME --UseClassId {CLSID}
```

The COM DLL is built in C++ at this moment and the core ".h" file looks like this:

```
class DECLSPEC_UUID("{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX1}") ImplementationClass : public ComClass<IInterfaceMain>
{
public:
    IFACEMETHODIMP Method1(IInterfaceSub1 **param1) _NOEXCEPT override { return 1; }
    IFACEMETHODIMP Method2(IInterfaceSub1** param2) _NOEXCEPT override { return 1; }
};

CoCreatableClass(ImplementationClass)
}}}
```

The interface it uses is defined thus:

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX2")
    IInterfaceMain : public IUnknown
    {
    public:
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Method1(IInterfaceSub1 **param1) = 0;        
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Method2(IInterfaceSub2 **param2) = 0;                       
    };
```

... and the interfaces used by the above are defined in a similar way.

Now, I want to create this COM DLL in .Net instead.  So the code currently looks like this:

```
[ComVisible(true), Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX1"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class ImplementationClass : IInterfaceMain
{
    public ImplementationClass() {}

    public int Method1(IInterfaceSub1 param1) { return 1; }
    public int Method2(IInterfaceSub2 param2) { return 1; }
}
```

I have created the main interface in C# also, like this (but without any MIDL_INTERFACE / Guid):

```
public interface IInterfaceMain
{
    int Method1(IInterfaceSub1 param1);
    int Method2(IInterfaceSub2 param2);
}
```

Invoking the main EXE (the code of which isn't available) returns these two errors depending on the build architecture (top is "x64" bottom is "Any CPU").

```
0x80004002 No such interface supported
0x800401f9 Error in the DLL.
```

As I said, I'm not fluent with C++ but to my mind this *should* work.

Comment: You have to attribute the interface as well.  Use [ComVisible], [Guid] and [InterfaceType]/

Comment: That's got it Hans, ta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of Hans Passant, the answer is to decorate the interfaces with the correct [ComVisible], [Guid] and [InterfaceType] attributes.